# как подружить async с классам?

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, asyncio

можно ли как то запустить класс в asyncio?
Есть утрированный код:

```
import asyncio
class ODB:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db
        self.table = None

    def get_end_time(self, ids, name):
        some_list = ["VOLG","TOMSK", "PERM"]
        if self.db in some_list:
            time.sleep(3)
            return time.time(), " it's ok ", self.db


async def run(info):                            
    o_db = ODB(info)
    values = await o_db.get_end_time("'1674', '1675', '9362'","'06_2022','05_2022'")
    return values

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [loop.create_task(run("VOLG")), loop.create_task(run("TOMSK"))]
done, _ = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))

print(done)     
loop.close()
```

Сейчас код не работает из-за `values = await o_db.get_end_time`.
Как можно одновременно вызвать создание двух классов с последующим асинхронным  выполнением?

Comment: Ну для начала сделать бы сам метод `get_end_time` асихнронным

Comment: но ведь await  не всегда ставится к асинхронным функциям. Но даже сделав `get_end_time` асинхронной, то  запуск происходит все равно последовательно.  
т.е. по факту  я получаю разницу во времени в 3 сек. в сообщениях. хотя по идее ожидаю, что будет одинаковое время

Comment: Если вы в коде специально прописали, что вы хотите дождаться завершения работы асинхронного метода — совершенно логично, что ваш код ждёт 3 секунды, пока метод завершится. Если вы не хотите ждать — значит и не надо прописывать код для ожидания (замените await на create_task или gather или типа того)

Comment: я понял о чем вы.
поменял
```async def get_end_time(self, ids, name):
        print(time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) ))
        some_list = ["VOLG","TOMSK", "PERM"]
        if self.db in some_list:
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            return time.time(), " it's ok ", self.db ```
забыл что есть sleep для asyncio. честно говоря  и не думал что там такая большая разница между этими двумя слипами. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать это с помощью `asyncio.gather(...)`.

Например, вместо этого:

```
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

Используйте это:

```
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```